# difference between Static and Abstract in Java with some example

Tags: java

I am a java beginner trying to learn some java.

Can any one give me overview of difference between Static and Abstract in Java with some example?

Comment: you just google it yourself.

Comment: There's no "difference", they're completely unrelated.

Comment: you are asking difference  between Ship and snake ....

Comment: [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and [Abstract Methods and Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal And top hit in a Google search now is... this question. Oh dear.

Answer (score 1):

There may be one difference is that we can not create an instance of abstract class but we can create an instance of static class.

for example

if have static class

```
static class ABC{
 void show(){
System.out.println("hello world");
}
}
```

//we can define function body in static class
to call show function we can create an instance of static class
like

```
ABC obj=new ABC();
obj.show();
```

it give out put

hello world

but in abstract class

```
abstract class ABC{
abstract public void show();
}
```

// we can only declare abstract function in abstract class
to call that function we have to create another class and extends abstract class

like

```
class Another extends ABC{
// now define function body of abstract functon
public void show(){
System.out.println("hello world");
}
}
```

now to print output we can create an instance of Another class

```
Another obj=new Another();
obj.show();
```

it will give you the output

hello world

i think this type of explanation you want

Answer (score 0):

```
static and `abstract` are two keyword in java,
```

it's depend where it's actually written i.e. before class/variable/method..etc.

Basically,
`static` can be written before `classes+instance-variables+instance-methods`, **after written it won't become instance** now it's change from *instance to class-level.*

`abstract` can be written in front of *class and methods* only.

Let's say, `static`  first then,

if you write `static` class (if class is inner) then it will become a member of outer class and behavior same as other `static member of class`.

if you write `static` in front of `instance-variable or instance-method` then it's **single** copy maintain through out as many object of that class.
*also, take care about while `inheritance` in case of.*

if `class` is `abstract` then you can not `instantiate` any object of that class whereas you must have to gone through `inheritance`.
if any method is `abstract` then you must have to override it, also be aware then if any **single method** is `abstract` then you must have to declare that class as an `abstract`.

So, i have just given overview of it. in detail all cover here is not possible.

Let me know if any serious matter i forget then.